# Вечный цикл в django как конвертер валют

Tags: python, django, циклы

Есть сайт на django. Сайт отображает курс валют. Мне нужно менять курс раз в 1 час. Для этого я сделал вечный цикл в `manage.py`, обновляющий информацию(записывает информацию в `cache`) о курсе, а далее уходит в спячку на 3600 секунд:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
while True:
    data = requests.get("http://data.fixer.io/api/XXXXXXXX").json()
    rates = data["rates"]
    
    cache.set("Converter", rates)
    time.sleep(3600)
```

Я понимаю, что это в корни неверный способ решения задачи. Как мне правильно реализовать вечный цикл в коде? Если это противоречит идеям Django, то как можно это иначе решить?

Comment: Посмотрите на [`Celery`](https://pypi.org/project/celery/) или [`Django APScheduler`](https://pypi.org/project/django-apscheduler/).

Comment: А что лучше использовать в коде Django: Celery или APScheduler? По Celery документацию нашел, а по APSschelduler - нет

Comment: Примеры по `Django APScheduler` можно посмотреть в его [репозитории](https://github.com/jarekwg/django-apscheduler). Кстати, есть ещё много подобных инструментов, например, [`django_dramatiq`](https://pypi.org/project/django-dramatiq/). Используйте то, что больше нравится.